# JavaMail and Gmail account suspended

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have a java program that send the output via email with attached the configuration file.

For this work I have registered an email on Gmail and I self-send the output from and to this email address.

Now google have suspended my account.

What i can do now? there is free email that i can configure with Java mail and that does not give me problems of this kind?

Comment: you should try rediffmail.com

Comment: Were you sending spam?  Were you sending a large volume of email?  You should contact Google to learn **why** they suspended your account.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/)

`GreenMail is an open source, intuitive and easy-to-use test suite of email servers for testing purposes.Supports SMTP, POP3, IMAP with SSL socket support`